# JQuery Alert Problem?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to get the following code to display only on specific pages but when I click through certain pages like the home page or any other pages that does not use this code I get the following `alert("some error occured, please try again later");.

How can I have the code not display the alert box on pages that do not use this JQuery code and still have the code work?

I'm using JQuery, PHP & MySQL.

Here is the JQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // get average rating
    getRatingText();
    // get average rating function
    function getRatingText(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../../update.php",
            data: "do=getavgrate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // add rating text
                $("#rating-text").text(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });
    }

    // get current rating
    getRating();
    // get rating function
    function getRating(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../../update.php",
            data: "do=getrate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // apply star rating to element dynamically
                $("#current-rating").css({ width: "" + result + "%" });
                 // add rating text dynamically
                $("#rating-text").text(getRatingText());
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });
    }


    // link handler
    $('#ratelinks li a').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../../update.php",
            data: "rating="+$(this).text()+"&do=rate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // remove #ratelinks element to prevent another rate
                $("#ratelinks").remove();
                // get rating after click
                getRating();
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a php code that can do this for me since I include this code in my php includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using an if to check if the `id="rating-text"` element is there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($("#rating-text").length) {
      // get average rating
      getRatingText();
      // get current rating
      getRating();
    }
    // get average rating function
    function getRatingText(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../../update.php",
            data: "do=getavgrate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // add rating text
                $("#rating-text").text(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });
    }

    function getRating(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../../update.php",
            data: "do=getrate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // apply star rating to element dynamically
                $("#current-rating").css({ width: "" + result + "%" });
                 // add rating text dynamically
                $("#rating-text").text(getRatingText());
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });
    }


    // link handler
    $('#ratelinks li a').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../../update.php",
            data: "rating="+$(this).text()+"&do=rate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // remove #ratelinks element to prevent another rate
                $("#ratelinks").remove();
                // get rating after click
                getRating();
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your functions for every document, because they're not triggered by a specific selector. Why not simply remove those calls to getRating() and getRatingText() outside of the $('#ratelinks li a').click()?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I have the code not display
>   the alert box on pages that do not use
>   this JQuery code and still have the
>   code work?

They do use it, that's the problem. One option is to move everything inside a function and only call the javascript function in the pages that need this code to run. If you have a php include like a header.inc you need to pass some parameter to your head and call the function only when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Tbere are different approaches to this problem:

1. Try inserting the code into a js file and include it via `<script src='' />` with the help of PHP.
2. Use a switch for every page that should include this script.
3. Use an absolute url for the `update.php` instead of a relative one.

For what I imagine you have, you need number 2. In a few minutes will post code about this.